# Fatal error lkn 1107: поврежденный или недопустимый файл

Tags: c++

Доброго времени суток! пытаюсь скомпилировать dll из командной строки visual studio 2010. 
ввожу такую комманду: cl /LD /EHsc array.h array.cpp - выдает ошибку: fatal error lnk 1107  поврежденный или  недопустимый файл.

в файле array.h это:

```
#ifndef _ARRAYDLL_H_
#define _ARRAYDLL_H_

#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<iomanip>
#include<locale.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<list>
#include<algorithm>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void array1();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void array2();
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void list1();

#endif
```

в чем проблема?

Comment: сделайте чистый build: удалите все временные файлы (`*.obj`, `*.pch`, `*.pdb`, `*.res`, что ещё там в каталоге Debug/Release) и перекомпилируйтесь.

Comment: я компилирую из командной строки - а не серез vs. у меня только 2 файла - array.h и array.cpp

Comment: тем не менее, компоновщик как-то умудряется найти и попытаться подлинковать неправильную библиотеку. либо у вас системная библиотека неправильная (чего в принципе не может быть), либо одна из библиотек в вашем рабочем каталоге (это уже может быть правдой). мой совет был как раз для устранения второго случая.